# Postgres lean Docker image containing only "psql" client

Tags: postgresql, docker, psql

I'm looking for a Docker image that would **only have all the necessary components to make calls to an external Postgres database using the `psql` client in the shell**. I do **not** need to launch a database locally or anything.

I found [jbergknoff/postgresql-client](https://hub.docker.com/r/jbergknoff/postgresql-client), which I haven't tested, but I'm just mostly surprised there doesn't seem to be any official image for that.

For now I'm using `postgres:12-alpine`, but it's only as part of a CronJob launched in Kubernetes which takes care of triggering a clean up of certain tables every once in a while by calling a Postgres function.

Anyone has something to recommend? Or some insight to share?

Comment: Building an image `FROM ubuntu` with a single `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install` command wouldn't be hard.  Mostly, though, it's easier to run interactive tools like `psql` directly from the host than to get them packaged in containers and `sudo docker run --rm -it registry.example.com/psql` for this kind of task.

Comment: If all you need is to run certain queries periodically you can take a look at [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) which does exactly that.

Comment: Precision: we use a managed Postgres server from `Azure`, which thus effectively means we cannot execute commands from within the host itself, nor can we use `pg_cron` because it isn't supported.

Answer (score 22):

IMHO, It's actually better to create our own Docker image instead of relying on some third party for such trivial need.
Supply chain security is already tricky enough.

Here is the content of my docker file `PgClientDockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.15
RUN apk --no-cache add postgresql12-client
ENTRYPOINT [ "psql" ]
```

Here is an excerpt from my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  pg_client:
    environment:
      PGDATABASE: ${pg_database}
      PGHOST: ${pg_host}
      PGPORT: ${pg_port}
      PGUSER: ${pg_user}
      PGPASSWORD: ${pg_password}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: PgClientDockerfile
```

I have an `.env` file with values like:

```
pg_database=mydb
pg_host=mydbhost
pg_port=5432
pg_user=myuser
pg_password=mypassword
```

And here is an example usage (for my use case):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

docker-compose run --rm pg_client -c 'drop trigger if exists my_trigger on my_table RESTRICT'
docker-compose run --rm another_docker_service ./run_batch_insert.sh
docker-compose run --rm pg_client -c 'create trigger my_trigger after insert or update or delete or truncate on my_table for each statement execute procedure refresh_my_table_finder()'
```

Answer (score 2):

I created an image for the exact purpose, only have the psql client. Here is the image on DockerHub
https://hub.docker.com/r/codingpuss/postgres-client

Simply create a container

```
docker run -dit --network=local_net --name=pgclient codingpuss/postgres-client
```

Then execute the command as you like:

```
docker exec -it pgclient psql postgresql://postgres:1@pgdb:5432/postgres -c 'select * from pg_catalog.pg_tables'
```